# I was told to reverse a number in python I did that but I can't remove comma after the last element

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, iteration

```
num=32768
x=0
y=0
while x<num:
    x=num%10
    y=num//10
    num=y
    print(x,end=',')
```

Here is my code the output shows 8,6,7,2,3, now how will I remove the comma after 3?

Comment: Why are there commas in the first place?  Numbers don't typically have commas after each digit.

Comment: What do you think `end=','` means?

Answer (score 1):

Put the digits in a list, then use `join()` to print the list with comma delimiters.

```
num=32768
x=0
y=0
result = []
while x<num:
    x=num%10
    y=num//10
    num=y
    result.append(str(x))
print(",".join(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

just add a condition to check if you have arrived at last number.

```
num=32768
x=0
y=0
while x<num:
    x=num%10
    y=num//10
    num=y
    if x >= num: 
        print(x, end='')
    else:
        print(x,end=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in one line:

```
 ",".join(str(32768)[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator, for example:

```py
num = 32768
x = 0
y = 0
while x < num:
    x = num % 10
    y = num // 10
    num = y
    print(x, end=',' if x < num else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach (assuming you aren't expressly forbidden from doing it this way) is to convert the whole number to a string and then reverse it.

```
>>> num = 32768
>>> print(str(num)[::-1])
86723
>>> print(','.join(str(num)[::-1]))
8,6,7,2,3
```